# Multiple linear regression: Is it normal that my error is so low?

Tags: multiple-regression

I am a little rusty when it comes to regression calculations, so I am not sure if my result is correct. Please help me understand what is happening here.

I have light passing through 5 filters. I don't know how much light each filter absorbs, but I can put them in and out of the optical path, which is what I do for each possible combination of filters (2^5-1=31 combinations). For combination i, the formula is
$$
I_{i} = I_{0}t_{1}^{x_{1,i}}t_{2}^{x_{2,i}}t_{3}^{x_{3,i}}t_{4}^{x_{4,i}}t_{5}^{x_{5,i}}
$$
with t being the (unknown) % of light transmitted through each filter. x is either 1 for "filter is in" or 0 for "filter is out".
Now, I can't put that formula into a regression model, I believe, so I used the logarithm:
$$
\log I_{i} = \log I_{0}+x_{1,i} \log t_{1}+x_{2,i} \log t_{2}+x_{3,i} \log t_{3}+x_{4,i} \log t_{4}+x_{5,i} \log t_{5}
$$
This is what I put into my multiple linear regression calculation:
$$
Y=\begin{pmatrix}\log I_{1} \\ \vdots \\ \log I_{31}\end{pmatrix}, 
X=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_{1,1} & \dots  & x_{1,5}      \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1  & x_{31,1} & \dots & x_{31,5}
\end{pmatrix}, 
\beta=\begin{pmatrix} \log I_{0} \\ \log t_{1} \\ \vdots \\ \log t_{5}\end{pmatrix}
$$
The solution to this type of regression is:
$$
\hat\beta=(X^T X)^{-1}X^TY, \\
\hat Y=X \hat \beta \\
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum (Y-\hat Y)^2}{31-5-1}
$$
And the errors for $\hat \beta$ are estimated by multiplying $\sigma$ with the diagonal elements of $(X^T X)^{-1}$.

For $\hat \beta$ and $\hat Y$, I get rid of the logarithm. The error values should stay the same since the exponential function is its own derivative and the values are small.

Now, the values for Y are correct - they're almost equal to the ones I got from my measurement. What confuses me though, is that the errors are negligibly small. The output intensity is found to be $(57 \pm 0.01) mJ$, and the relative error values for the filters are all exactly the same with $\frac{\Delta \beta}{\beta} =0.000097$.

Is this possible? How does this make any sense? I'm guessing they are equal because the formula only estimates them? But then why are they so low?
I also find it confusing that the calculation does not consider the error values of Y. I mean, the calculation *is* very good - the highest residuals are something like .5, many are lower. But it seems implausible to me that the calculation basically tells me that the result for the filter values is *perfect*.

But I don't know. Maybe you can shed some light on this. Was my measurement just that good?

Comment: I find it a bit difficult to relate this to standard regression. As I read it the $x_i$ and the $t_i$ are all data so there is nothing to estimate here except the intercept $I_0$. I'd like to see the output from a statistical program, which would flag this situation. Otherwise put, what is inside your vector $\beta$? How many parameters do you think are in there?

Comment: Hi, the $t_{i}$ are unknown as well as $I_{0}$, so I'd like to know these values and they are what's inside $\beta$. (I'm not using a statistical program, I wrote my own IDL code for this, so I can't tell you the output of a statistical program unfortunately.)
X (the matrix of 1s and 0s) and Y (the measured intensities) are the input.

Comment: Excellent; that makes it clearer. Well, OK, you have 6 parameters then $\log I_0$ and the $\log t_i$. Seemingly that's enough for a good model but this is physics after all! Watch out though: nothing in the machinery guarantees that $\exp(\log t_i) \le 1$, which presumably is required physically. (Disclosure: no physics courses after age 15, much to my regret.)

Comment: Just to clarify, I *did* the calculation already and the values fit very well, all of them. I just wonder why my errors are almost non-existant. Because you're exactly right, this is not how physics usually works! And personally I would have estimated that my measured intensities had an uncertainty of about 10% (I had to measure quickly so as not to destroy my detector), but this estimated error didn't even figure into the calculation. This seems different than what I remember from linear regression.

Comment: On the contrary, my prejudice is that in physics you should have good quality data and laws of nature to help! Everything is relative: you should try a week in social science where people lie, forget, misunderstand, ignore the question, etc. and then you have to do the data analysis. Of course, your regression calculation doesn't know about your measurement uncertainty.